# Why is the VS C++ linker returning "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" with mixed DLL forwards?

Tags: c++, dll, forward, mixed

I want to make a wrapper DLL because I need to monitor the calls so I can make use of the DLL myself for another project. I have no documentation of the wrapped DLL. I used the wrapper2.cpp project of Michael Chourdakis to create the initial source code below, but I run into problems, and I think because the DLL I want to wrap is a mix of C and C++ exports.

Can somebody explain me why the first code is not linking, while the second does? My knowledge of C++ is limited, but I need to use it, because Delphi (for my project) is unable to handle the managed C++ exports (afaik).

IcuSort.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

HINSTANCE hLThis = 0;
HINSTANCE hL = 0;
FARPROC p[13] = {0};

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID)
    {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
        hLThis = hInst;
        hL = LoadLibrary(_T("IcuSortOLD.DLL"));
        if (!hL) return false;
        }
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        {
        FreeLibrary(hL);
        }

    return 1;
    }
```

IcuSort.def:

```
EXPORTS
??0ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@ABV0@@Z=IcuSortOLD.??0ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@ABV0@@Z @1
??0ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@PB_WGG@Z=IcuSortOLD.??0ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@PB_WGG@Z @2
??1ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@XZ=IcuSortOLD.??1ct_IcuNumber@@QAE@XZ @3
??4ct_IcuNumber@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z=IcuSortOLD.??4ct_IcuNumber@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z @4
??8ct_IcuNumber@@QAE_NABV0@@Z=IcuSortOLD.??8ct_IcuNumber@@QAE_NABV0@@Z @5
?Clear@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEXXZ=IcuSortOLD.?Clear@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEXXZ @6
?GetFormattedNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEPB_WXZ=IcuSortOLD.?GetFormattedNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEPB_WXZ @7
?GetOrgNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEPB_WXZ=IcuSortOLD.?GetOrgNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEPB_WXZ @8
?Init@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEXPB_WGG@Z=IcuSortOLD.?Init@ct_IcuNumber@@QAEXPB_WGG@Z @9
?IsSameNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAE_NABV1@_N@Z=IcuSortOLD.?IsSameNumber@ct_IcuNumber@@QAE_NABV1@_N@Z @10
deleteICUSortKey=IcuSortOLD.deleteICUSortKey @11
getICULastError=IcuSortOLD.getICULastError @12
getICUSortKey=IcuSortOLD.getICUSortKey @13
```

Command line:

```
cl.exe /EHsc /LD IcuSort.cpp /link /DEF:IcuSort.def
```

This gives this error:

```
IcuSort.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol deleteICUSortKey
IcuSort.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol getICULastError
IcuSort.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol getICUSortKey
IcuSort.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

However, when I use this source code, it compiles/links without any error, and all the functions of IcuSortOld.dll are properly relayed through IcuSort.dll.

IcuSort.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

HINSTANCE hLThis = 0;
HINSTANCE hL = 0;
FARPROC p[13] = {0};

FARPROC lpfndeleteICUSortKey;
FARPROC lpfngetICULastError;
FARPROC lpfngetICUSortKey;

typedef unsigned long int (__cdecl * pICFUNC1)(unsigned long int, unsigned long int, unsigned long int, unsigned long int);
typedef int (__cdecl * pICFUNC2)(int);
typedef int (__cdecl * pICFUNC3)();

pICFUNC2 My_deleteICUSortKey; 
pICFUNC3 My_getICULastError;
pICFUNC1 My_getICUSortKey; 

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID)
    {
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
        hLThis = hInst;
        hL = LoadLibrary(_T("IcuSortOLD.DLL"));
        if (!hL) return false;

        // Get function pointer
        FARPROC lpfndeleteICUSortKey = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hL),"deleteICUSortKey"); 
        FARPROC lpfngetICULastError = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hL),"etICULastError"); 
        FARPROC lpfngetICUSortKey = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hL),"getICUSortKey"); 
        }
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        {
        FreeLibrary(hL);
        }

    return 1;
    }

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT int deleteICUSortKey(int arg1) {
  return 1;
}

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT int getICULastError() {
  return 1;
}

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT unsigned long int getICUSortKey(unsigned long int arg1, unsigned long int arg2, unsigned long int arg3, unsigned long int arg4) {
  return 1;
}
```

Why is the declaration of those C functions making it work, while the .DEF file is clearly forwarding them to IcuSortOld.dll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I can find no official confirmation of this from Microsoft, this is a bug in MSVC's linker.

When it encounters a .def, it verifies that the .def's EXPORTS section does not mention any missing symbols. It appears to do this by building a symbol table using the following rules for each export:

1. If the export has an *internal_name*, select that.
2. Otherwise, select the *entryname*
3. If the selected name contains `@`, don't include it in the symbol table (no idea why this is a rule)
4. Otherwise, add it to the table of symbols to check

...and then it ensures that every symbol in the table is provided by one of the objects/libraries presented for linking. If not, it throws a LNK2001 error for the symbol(s), naming the .def as the file at fault. This is apparently intended to help the programmer find typos in the .def more quickly.

The missing rule (giving rise to the bug) is that, if an export is actually a forward, it should not be adding anything to the needed-symbols table, because DLL forwards are "made up" symbols that have no meaning at compile-time.

In your first example, there are plenty of forwards, some of which contain `@` (thus are ignored), while others, which do not contain `@`, are hence required to be defined in a library/object to avoid the linker error. In your second example, you ensure that those symbols that lack `@` exist at link-time, satisfying the linker's (misbehaving) check.

One suitable workaround would be to put stub functions in a source file for all names not containing `@` (as you have done); but note also that `LIB.EXE` (which doesn't do the above symbol checking) isn't afflicted by this same bug, so it may be possible to pass the .def to *that*, use it to generate a .exp (which contains the raw exports directory for the output DLL), and pass that .exp to the linker instead of the .def.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I was under the impression that the @ in the forward names was because of the C++ name mangling and not to ignore those. And the other/last three are simply C forwards and therefore lacking @ in their names. No?