How to create in Rust a forwarded dll export with a mangled name
I'm trying to create a Windows DLL in Rust that proxies one of its exported functions to a function in another dll (other.dll). The problem is that the other.dll exported name is mangled, something similar to this: ?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z. As far as I know, Rust does not allow a function name that contains such characters.
For now, I've tried declaring an empty function on my code and then using a .def file to give it an alias and convert it into a forwarded export. Something similar to this:
lib.rs
#[no_mangle]
fn normal_function() {
}

file.def
EXPORTS
?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z=normal_function
?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z=c:\other\dll\path.?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG @1

This .def file properly exports the function with the desired alias (?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z), but the second line of the file is completely ignored by the linker. Therefore, the function is not forwarded to other.dll when it is called.
Is there any way in Rust to create a forwarded exported function with a specific mangled name?
In short, I have one DLL existing.dll which already exists and I'm writing another dll in Rust rust.dll. existing.dll has an exported function named WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z. I want to create in rust.dll the same exported function so that, when someone calls the function from rust.dll, it forwards the call to the same function in existing.dll.

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the def file. You can't export the same symbol multiple times. I think what you want is just the first line, then in your implementation you need to load and call the target function.

Do you mean that you have two DLLs: existing.dll which already exists and rust.dll which you're writing, both DLLs should export a function named ?WriteStuff@CBuffer@@QEAAJPEBG@Z, and when someone calls the function from rust.dll it should forward the call to existing.dll? Or do you mean something else? In which case please edit your question to include a concrete example of which DLL contains which function, who calls who and what should happen.

@Jmb Exactly what you said it's what I'm trying to achieve. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

You can call the mangled function from rust by declaring it within an extern block with a rust-local name, but the desired link_name.   You can then export your function (whatever its rust-local name) with the name of your choice via the export_name attribute.  Linking might be a mess, however...

@Luke well, I definitely could do so, but it is not what I'm trying to achieve. A forwarded export is dealed by the system's loader, and thats my final goal, not to implement in my own code the logic required to load  existing.dll and call the desired function, although the result could look very similar.

So then you just want only the second line in the file.def file, right? Not sure what Rust has to do with anything if all you want is to export a forwarded function.

Ideally I would need only the second line, but if I compile just with that line the linker throws an "unresolved symbol" error message. That's why I need the first line as well, or something similar I guess. And regarding the Rust part... well, the dll is written in Rust, I need to deal with this issue from the features offered by that specific language.

Possible issue with linker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700994/179634
